# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create tables in oracle application express. All the tables created well except of Chessplayer and i really don't know what's the matter. 
Can somebody please tell me what's wrong with the SQL below.

```
DROP TABLE Сhessplayer CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;

CREATE TABLE Chessplayer
  (
    Chessplayer_ID                   INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    Surname                          CHAR (50) ,
    Name                             CHAR (40) ,
    Fathers_name                     CHAR (40) ,
    Side                             CHAR (10) ,
    Birth_date                       DATE ,
    Date_of_entering                 DATE ,
    Privelegies                      CLOB ,
    Levels                           INTEGER Levels > 0 AND Levels < 6 ,
    Part_ID                          INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    Money_ID                         INTEGER NOT NULL
  ) ;

ALTER TABLE Chessplayer ADD CONSTRAINT Chessplayer_PK PRIMARY KEY ( Chessplayer_ID ) ;

INSERT INTO Chessplayer VALUES 
    (1,'Ivanov','Igor','Vladimirivich','WHITE', to_date('6-8-1993','dd-mm-yyyy'), to_date('17-1-2013','dd-mm-yyyy'), 'SUPER SMART',1,1,1);
INSERT INTO Chessplayer VALUES 
    (2,'Sokolov','Andrey','Semenovich','BLACK', to_date('20-8-1994','dd-mm-yyyy'), to_date('15-6-2014','dd-mm-yyyy'), 'SUPER SMART',1,1,1);
INSERT INTO Chessplayer VALUES 
    (3,'Smelev','Victor','Petrovich','WHITE', to_date('11-9-1992','dd-mm-yyyy'), to_date('21-12-2014','dd-mm-yyyy'), 'SUPER SMART',1,2,1);  
INSERT INTO Chessplayer VALUES 
    (4,'Sidorov','Sergey','Igorevich','BLACK', to_date('6-8-1993','dd-mm-yyyy'), to_date('17-1-2013','dd-mm-yyyy'), 'SUPER SMART',1,2,1);
INSERT INTO Chessplayer VALUES 
    (5,'Sidorov','Sergey','Igorevich','BLACK', to_date('6-8-1993','dd-mm-yyyy'), to_date('17-1-2013','dd-mm-yyyy'), 'SUPER SMART',1,3,1);
INSERT INTO Chessplayer VALUES 
    (6,'Ivanov','Igor','Vladimirivich','WHITE', to_date('6-8-1993','dd-mm-yyyy'), to_date('17-1-2013','dd-mm-yyyy'), 'SUPER SMART',1,3,1);

INSERT INTO Chessplayer VALUES 
    (7,'Timurov','Aleksey','Geogrievich','WHITE', to_date('6-8-1993','dd-mm-yyyy'), to_date('17-1-2013','dd-mm-yyyy'), 'SUPER SMART',1,1,2);
INSERT INTO Chessplayer VALUES 
    (8,'Antonevich','Egor','Vasilievich','BLACK', to_date('6-8-1993','dd-mm-yyyy'), to_date('17-1-2013','dd-mm-yyyy'), 'SUPER SMART',1,1,2);
INSERT INTO Chessplayer VALUES 
    (9,'Stepanov','Aleksandr','Vladimirivich','WHITE', to_date('6-8-1993','dd-mm-yyyy'), to_date('17-1-2013','dd-mm-yyyy'), 'SUPER SMART',1,2,2);   
INSERT INTO Chessplayer VALUES 
    (10,'Kireev','Vadim','Sergeevich','BLACK', to_date('6-8-1993','dd-mm-yyyy'), to_date('17-1-2013','dd-mm-yyyy'), 'SUPER SMART',1,2,2);
INSERT INTO Chessplayer VALUES 
    (11,'Timurov','Aleksey','Geogrievich','BLACK', to_date('6-8-1993','dd-mm-yyyy'), to_date('17-1-2013','dd-mm-yyyy'), 'SUPER SMART',1,3,2);
INSERT INTO Chessplayer VALUES 
    (12,'Stepanov','Aleksandr','Vladimirivich','WHITE', to_date('6-8-1993','dd-mm-yyyy'), to_date('17-1-2013','dd-mm-yyyy'), 'SUPER SMART',1,3,2);  


ALTER TABLE Chessplayer ADD CONSTRAINT Chesspl_Reg_contr_FK FOREIGN KEY ( Money_ID ) REFERENCES Reg_contribution ( Reg_contr_ID ) ;

ALTER TABLE Chessplayer ADD CONSTRAINT Chessplayer_Party_FK FOREIGN KEY ( Part_ID ) REFERENCES Party ( Party_ID ) ;
```

And here's the errors in oracle application express:
CREATE TABLE Chessplayer ( Chessplayer_ID           ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

ALTER TABLE Chessplayer ADD CONSTRAINT Chessplayer_PK PRIMAR            ORA-02260: table can have only one primary key

and for all inserts:
ORA-01722: invalid number

Comment: Where [in the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/toc.htm) did you find the syntax: `INTEGER Levels > 0 AND Levels < 6`. Also: you most probably do **not** want `CHAR` but `VARCHAR`

Comment: I"m guessing the table already exists and has a primary key, so you can't create it again, and the alter table fails. For the inserts, your date format specifies leading zeros but your date strings do not have them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have written the table creation this way

```
-- Create table
create table CHESSPLAYER
(
  CHESSPLAYER_ID   INTEGER not null,
  SURNAME          CHAR(50),
  NAME             CHAR(40),
  FATHERS_NAME     CHAR(40),
  SIDE             CHAR(10),
  BIRTH_DATE       DATE,
  DATE_OF_ENTERING DATE,
  PRIVELEGIES      CLOB,
  LEVELS           INTEGER,
  PART_ID          INTEGER not null,
  MONEY_ID         INTEGER not null
);

-- Create/Recreate check constraints 
alter table CHESSPLAYER
  add constraint CHKLEV
  check (Levels > 0 AND Levels < 6);
```

That should solve all of your problems

Comment: OP script starts with a drop, so basically he modifies the creation part, and run the full script i guess

Comment: Yes, thank you  very much, table created, but my inserts still not working
I tried adding zeroes to date but it didn't work

Comment: Thanks everyone very much, i solved problem. I had table Chessplayer before creating it and it didn't dropped when i wrote it in code (i don't know why), so i dropped it by myself in object browser in application express.